# MS-Access SQL Subquery with same values issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

Good evening,

My issue is when I run my query it has everything I want, but my sub-query doesn't seem to work properly.  It has the same value for all my customers.  I'm really not sure how to defeat this problem.  If I add in a CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE in it then it requests me to use an EXISTS.  So the Avg is working? I decided to use the Avg aggregate function and I received the same problem.

**My Tables are:**

- CUSTOMER(CUS_CODE)
- INVOICE(CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER)
- LINE(INV_NUMBER, LINE_NUMBER, LINE_UNITS,LINE_PRICE)

In this question I'm working on trying to get the average purchase amount per product made by each customer, using a subquery.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME AS Name, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE, Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*
[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) AS Total_purchases, Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER) AS Number_of_purchases, 
(
SELECT Avg([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE])
FROM INVOICE, LINE
WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
) AS Average_purchase_amount

FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE, LINE
WHERE ((CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE)=[INVOICE].[CUS_CODE]) AND ((INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)=[LINE].[INV_NUMBER])
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE;
```

My error seems to be in the way I implment my subquery.  How do I make it average for each customer.  For instance in the INVOICE table I have many customers that have multiple invoices, hence they have ordered many diffrent items.  So for each invoice that is by the same customer I want to count of the average price and then take the average of that price by how many products they ordered.

> I feel my head exploding at this point

If you have any questions or need more infromation I will update.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST**

You need to look at your where clause in the subquery.  You are comparing where INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER. 
The issue is that you are not connecting all the way to your CUS_CODE in the CUSTOMER Table so the interceptor does not know you want to do this for each separate customer.  Simple fix.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME AS Name, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE, Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*  
[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) AS Total_purchases, Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER) AS Number_of_purchases, 

(
SELECT Avg([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE])
FROM INVOICE, LINE
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE AND INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
) AS Average_purchase_amount

FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE, LINE
WHERE ((CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE)=[INVOICE].[CUS_CODE]) AND ((INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)=[LINE].[INV_NUMBER])
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE;
```

As you can see I added in the first WHERE clause that CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE AND ...What was already there.

Now it should work by counting each invoice that the customer had and then adds up the amounts and totals them and takes the average.